# Rails 4 - PG Search not returning exact match with tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, tags, pg-search

On rails 4 with the acts as taggable gem. My search is currently not returning exact matches first. It seems to be like the tags aren't being weighted properly. When I get rid of the `:associated_against => { :tags => {:name => 'D'}}` exact matches are returned first. Has anyone ran into this issue before? Any suggestions?

Here is my search scope:

```
pg_search_scope :search, :against => { :specific => 'A', :title => 'B', :aka => 'B'},
                        :associated_against => { :tags => {:name => 'D'}},
                        :using => { dmetaphone: {}, tsearch: { dictionary: 'english' }, 
                        trigram: {:threshold => 0.3} },
                        ignoring: :accents
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the rest of your code in the controller, etc.  I have the following in my app:

```
# tools.rb    
include PgSearch
        pg_search_scope :search_including_tags,
        :against => [:description, :barcode],
        :associated_against => {:tags => [:name] }
```

Then in my controller to search through I have:

```
#tools_controller.rb
    def index
        if params[:search]
          @tools = Tool.where("(barcode) LIKE (?)", "%#{params[:search]}")
        elsif params[:tag]
          @tools = Tool.tagged_with(params[:tag])
        elsif params[:id]
          @tool = Tool.find(params[:id])
        else
          @tools = Tool.all
          @tool = Tool.first
        end
      end
```

and finally for my search controller

```
def new
  @tools = Tool.search_including_tags(params[:query])
end
```

Hope this helps.  Can't really say much without seeing all of the code. But I ended up using this which worked: `:associated_against => {:tags => [:name] }`